# Possible to find the service path of all running relays in an Azure namespace when display mode is set private?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebusrelay

This seems basic but i cant seem to find an answer. Even service bus explorer sample app can't see private relay services.
Our application will be creating multiple relays using the Azure Service bus, These can be set to Discover mode public and that will list them in the service registry on the namespace however this information being "public" isn't acceptable to us.

Is there a way to get a list of all active relays in a namespace without setting them to public? The Azure portal is able to obviously but i'm not able to find a way to get this list programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NamespaceManager.GetAsync() for this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.servicebus.namespacemanager.getrelaysasync.aspx

Comment: Worked great after going from 2.1.0? to 2.1.3.